# Python Read Number From Certain Digit

Tags: python-3.x

So i tried to read a number from a digit for example

```
integer_var = 12345679
```

i want to read it from 5 to 8 digit. So the output will be like this

`Last 4 Digits = 5679`

i've tried with `int(str(integer_var)[:-4]` but the output is `123`

Here is my code:

```
integer_var = 12345679
result = int(str(integer_var)[:-4])
print("Last 4 Digits = ", result)
```

Comment: ```int(str(integer_var)[4:])```

Comment: or  ```int(str(integer_var)[-4:])```

Comment: @kareem_emad. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[start:end:step]
result = int(str(integer_var)[-4:])
```